# Custom Attribute on order confirmation email in Magento 2.4.5

Tags: custom-attributes, magento2.4.5, order-confirmation

I'm trying to publish the custom attribute "flash_sale" (dropdown) on order confirmations.

I've changed the file:

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml
```

and inserted the additional line:

```
<p style="color: #aaaaaa;"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Flash Sale') ?>: <?= $block>escapeHtml($block->getflash_sale()) ?></p>
```

with the result:

```
     <td class="item-info<?php if ($block->getItemOptions()): ?> has-extra<?php endif; ?>" colspan="2" style="position: relative !important; border-top: 0 none !important; padding: 35px 10px; border-bottom: 1px dotted #000000;">
    <p class="item-name" style="margin-top: 0 !important;"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></p>
    <div class="item-detail" style="margin: 5px 0; font-size: 12px;">
    <p style="color: #aaaaaa;"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Item') ?>: <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getSku($_item)) ?></p>
     <p style="color: #aaaaaa;"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Flash Sale') ?>: <?= $block>escapeHtml($block->getflash_sale()) ?></p>
        <?php if ($block->getItemOptions()): ?>
            <?php foreach ($block->getItemOptions() as $option): ?>
                <p style="color: #aaaaaa"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $option['label']. ': ' . nl2br($option['value'])?></p>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

But the value is not published on order confirmations. What went wrong?

Thank you advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. Coding standard: method name should be `getFlashSale` instead of `getflash_sale`.
2. Try to replace `$block->getflash_sale()` with `$_item->getGiftFlashSale()`.

Comment: If this answer helps you resolve your issue, please mark it as **accepted**. That indicates your issue is solved and helps others with the same issue find out the verified answer easily.

Answer (score 0):

You should check some item below:

- Where did you store the **flash_sale** value? From order item or order?
- Did it saved correctly? With order confirmation email, the value of an item should be stored in table sales_order_item.
- You shouldn't load the value from product.
- Your code block **$block->getflash_sale()**, Is function **getflash_sale** defined in the block class?
- 

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your hits.

These were the changes i have made and now works as expected:

1. I'm using the Pearl Theme, so i've added the lines 16-18 to weltpixel-default.phtml :

   `<?php
   // @codingStandardsIgnoreFile`

   /** @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\DefaultItems */
   /** @var $_item \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item */
   $_item = $block->getItem();
   $_order = $_item->getOrder();
   $prodImg = $block->getImage($block->getProductForThumbnail(), 'cart_page_product_thumbnail');
   /** @var  $wpHelper \WeltPixel\EnhancedEmail\Helper\Data */
   $wpHelper = $this->helper('WeltPixel\EnhancedEmail\Helper\Data');
   if ($wpHelper->displaySalesPricesExclTax()) {
   $itemPrice = $_item->getPrice();
   } else {
   $itemPrice = $_item->getPriceInclTax();
   }
   **$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   $productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
   $product = $productRepository->get($_item->getSKU());**
   ?>

and inserted the additional line in the same file:

```
 <p style="color: #aaaaaa;"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Flash Sale') ?>: <?= $product->getAttributeText('FlashSale') ?></p>
```

with the result

```
<td class="item-info<?php if ($block->getItemOptions()): ?> has-extra<?php endif; ?>" colspan="2" style="position: relative !important; border-top: 0 none !important; padding: 35px 10px; border-bottom: 1px dotted #000000;">
    <p class="item-name" style="margin-top: 0 !important;"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></p>
    <div class="item-detail" style="margin: 5px 0; font-size: 12px;">
    <p style="color: #aaaaaa;"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Item') ?>: <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getSku($_item)) ?></p>
     <p style="color: #aaaaaa;"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Flash Sale') ?>: <?= $product->getAttributeText('FlashSale') ?></p>
        <?php if ($block->getItemOptions()): ?>
            <?php foreach ($block->getItemOptions() as $option): ?>
                <p style="color: #aaaaaa"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $option['label']. ': ' . nl2br($option['value'])?></p>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```